# Instant sort when put new value in array C++

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I have a dynamically allocated array containing structs with a key pair value. I need to write an update(key,value) function that puts new struct into array or if struct with same key is already in the array it needs to update its value. Insert and Update is combined in one function.

The problem is:

- Before adding a struct I need to check if struct with this key already existing.

  I can go through all elements of array and compare key (very slow)

  Or I can use binary search, but (!) array must be sorted.

  So I tried to sort array with each update (sloooow) or to sort it when calling binary search funtion.....which is each time updating

Finally, I thought that there must be a way of inserting a struct into array so **it would be placed in a right place and be always sorted.**

However, I couldn't think of an algorithm like that so I came here to ask for some help because google refuses to read my mind.

I need to make my code faster because my array accepts more that 50 000 structs and I'm using bubble sort (because I'm dumb).

Comment: You should use a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). The `insert` and `delete` methods do ensure that the heap stays sorted, and it is fast (both operations are `O(log n)`.

Comment: @Yochert The other approach is to use std::map instead of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a different data structure. As there is no genuine need to keep the structs ordered, there is only need to detect if the struct with the same key exits, so the costs of maintaining order in a balanced tree (for instance by using `std::map`) are excessive. A more suitable data structure would be a hash table. C++11 provides such in the standard library under obscure name `std::unordered_map` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

If you insist on using an array, a possible approach might be to combine these algorithms:

1. Bloom filter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)
2. Partial sort (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort)
3. Binary search

Maintain two ranges in the array -- first goes a range that is already sorted, then goes a range that is not yet. When you insert a struct, first check with the bloom filter if a matching struct might already exist. If the bloom filter gives a negative answer, then just insert the struct at the end of the array. After that the sorted range does not change, the unsorted range grows by one.

If the bloom filter gives a positive answer, then apply partial sort algorithm to make the entire array sorted and then use binary search to check if such an object actually exists. If so, replace this element. After that the sorted range is the entire array, and the unsorted range is empty.

If the binary search has shown that the bloom filter was wrong, and the matching struct is not there, then you just put the new struct at the end of the array. After that the sorted range is entire array minus one, and the unsorted range is the last element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Red Black Trees: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

They will ensure the data is always sorted, and it has a complexity of O ( log n ) for inserts.

A binary heap will not suffice, as a binary heap does not have guaranteed sort order, your only guarantee is that the top element is either min or max.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you insert an element, binary search to find if it exists. If it doesn't exist, the binary search will give you the index at which you can insert it.

Comment: In this case it will be necessary to copy to the next position N / 2 elements on average, where N is the current array size. As this algorithm is applied for every element so the total number of copy operations would be N * N / 4. This might be too expensive for large values of N. For an array of 100 thousand elements this means 2.5 billions of copy operations.

Comment: @AlekseyDemakov Not necessarily; OP could use a linked list or `std::deque`, which offers linear-time middle insertion. (`std::vector` does as well, but occasionally takes significantly more time to insert an element while it reserves itself more memory.)

Comment: Well, N / 2 is indeed linear time. This is what I say. But linear time for single element translates to quadratic time if it is applied to every of N elements.

Comment: @AlekseyDemakov "if it is applied to every of N elements", which is not necessarily what happens in the above data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), which does not allow duplicate elements and places elements in sorted position. This assumes that you are storing the key and value in a struct, and not separately. In order for the sorting to work properly, you will need to define a comparison function for the structs.